# Cannot load swf file from http source(wildfly server) in Chrome?

Tags: flash

Cannot load swf file(http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf) from Chrome. It can load the very same file from Chrome when it is located on the hard drive. I am using flash 32.0.0.171 and Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit). Other browsers like IE have similar issue. When i use F12 to debug the issue there is no errors and crossdomain is not use, only the swf file is retrieving with a GET request.

This swf file is generated by the compiler version Adobe AIR 3.7 SDK. i cannot install the latest SDK for some reason.

1. If i enter http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf in Chrome, it is automatically downloaded . If I enter the swf file(CDdemo.swf) of this link 
   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154182/why-is-google-chrome-blocking-raw-swf-playback, it is correctly loaded on the same browser and flash plays CDdemo.swf correctly. I attempted to use the same object code as in the html example of the previous link but nothing get displayed.
2. If i use a html file which use a swf located on the hard disk flash can read it and load correctly the flash. This code works :

```
<object name="play" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="C:/tmp/my_file.swf"
```

3. I have used a relative path com.mypackage/my_file.swf instead of http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf. Chrome give log nototifying a get request was successful (200) for this swf. However the file is still not read by Flash.
4. I attempted to use the following code but nothing get displayed too :

```
<object width="800" height="600" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0">

    <embed src="http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf" quality="high"type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="600" />
</object>
```

5. I also use flashplayer_32_sa_debug.exe in order to debug the swf file. When i use the swf file on my local hardisk it works, but when i use the url  http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf it crashed with no error. I guess it is a authentication issue in that case. Generally i authenticate on my_server and then attempt to load the swf file.
6. If i use another swf file , i got nothing displayed either. i strongly suspect that there is a blockage on my Wildfly server. I can load this SWF file on the very same Chrome with a jetty server. To my mind it is a Wildfly specific issue.

This is also the original code that use to work but now does not get displayed on the Chrome browser :

```
<body>
<object name="play" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://my_server:8080/service/com.mypackage/my_file.swf" 
id="play" style="margin:0 10px;width:1000;height:1000;" allowScriptAccess="always">

<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashvars" value="myvalue=blah" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="autoplay" value="true" />



</object>
</body>
```

On the Wildfly server access log i have this INFO logs :

> INFO  [io.undertow.accesslog] (default task-12) 167.22.22.22 - 0a658140-8ad8-4347-910b-796e651a12cf [27/Apr/2019:12:32:45 +0000] "GET /my_service/my_file.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 116887 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

I expect to play the swf file and display the content. It should be "load in progress...". Nothing is being displayed and only a log (200 OK) is shown about swf file being downloaded correctly with GET request.

Comment: Your _"original code that use to work"_ seems to work fine for me (note: my URL did not involve port `8080`) and I replaced `style="margin:0 10px;width:1000;height:1000;"` with `width="400" height="400"` for the size of my own testing SWF. So maybe using port 8080 is the problem... Using Chrome's Developer Tools option, **(1)** Check via **network** tab for any request for a file `crossdomain.xml`? **(2)** Check via **console** tab for any errors. **(3)** Did you change anything recently like your server provider or maybe changed from using local host to the online host?

Comment: When i use F12 there is no errors on client side but only a 200 OK  GET request to retrieve the swf file on network tab. Crossdomain.html is not retrieved . I am using a localhost. The swf file is located on a Wildfly server running inside a docker ( new change).  Wildfly access log : INFO  [io.undertow.accesslog] (default task-12) 167.22.22.22 - 0a658140-8ad8-4347-910b-796e651a12cf [27/Apr/2019:12:32:45 +0000] "GET /my_service/my_file.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 116887 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to allow swf extension as flash mime type in web.wml configuration.  The filter "x-content-type-options" on Wildfly server was blocking swf files

```
<filter-ref name="x-content-type-options"/>
```

Since this swf file was correctly loaded with a jetty server,  i had to assume it was my Wildfly server the culprit.

also